# How can I determine that setMaxRows limited the number of rows returned (JDBC)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, dao

Using JDBC and no particular framework like Hibernate or JSTL libraries. (just JDBC driver *mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar*)

Given a table that has between 20 and 25 rows and a prepared statement on which I have set .setMaxRows(20), how can I determine that the 20 rows returned were in fact out of possibly more than 20 rows? (I have also tried with ... *LIMIT 20* in the SQL statement)

I know that JSTL makes `${myRs.limitedByMaxRows}` available when using `<sql:query var="myRs" ... maxRows="20">...` but I'd like to find out how this can be detected from within a pojo DAO.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am trying to understand your question. Are you trying to create pagination? Also, which library can one find the `sql:` JSTL functions?

Comment: JSTL stands for JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library, see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html - I'm not looking for a system solution here, All I'm trying to do is summarized in the title - regardless of the "why"

Comment: I know what JSTL means @Mike. I don't understand where the JSTL `sql` tag comes from. Besides, the answer you seek may require you to understand the JDBC API as well as implementations of the API by the RDBMS vendors. Not all of them have a JDBC compliant driver.

Comment: Hi @Buhake, the sql tag is part of JSTL (jstl-api-1.2.jar, jstl-impl-1.2.jar) and here's an example of how to use it in a jsp page:
`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<sql:query var="invRs" dataSource="jdbc/invDs">
select sku, name from INVENTORY
</sql:query>
<c:forEach var="widget" items="${invRs.rows}">
  ${widget.sku}: ${widget.name}
</c:forEach>`

Comment: Thanks @Mike. I didn't know that JSTL had the `sql` tag. I learned something new. :-D

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the source of the MySQL connector and it turns out that *MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet* does not indicate whether the result returned was actually limited by using `setMaxRows` on the prepared statement.

As for the JSTL *`sql`* tag and its implementation of `maxRows`, it's somewhat misleading. It does not actually use `.setMaxRows()` on its prepared statement especially because it needs to determine if the limit was reached but more rows exist, to be able to set `limitedByMaxRows` to `true`. So the query executed on the DB is not *actually* limited.

So the solution I will be implementing in a POJO when setting `.setMaxRows()` is as follows:

```
if (pstmt.getMaxRows() > 0 && rowCount == pstmt.getMaxRows()) {
  try ( ResultSet countRs =
      conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select count(*) from INVENTORY") 
      ) {
    if (countRs.first()) {
      limitReached = rowCount < countRs.getInt(1);
    }
  }
}
```